# C# Unexpected Symbol }

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, console

I am brand new to CSHARP, but I am very fluent to javascript.

I am writing a Plugin for Rust, a multiplayer game, this plugin will be handled through a modloader called Oxide.
[Oxide API](http://docs.oxidemod.org/rust/?csharp#broadcastchat)

The error i get :

```
[Oxide] 6:30 AM [Error] Sulfur plugin failed to compile!
[Oxide] 6:30 AM [Error] Sulfur.cs(19,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}'
```

I have literately copied my code directly from Oxide's API page, and compiled it. But i get a very weird error that i have tried adding and taking things out, the error appears to be invoked at this line

```
namespace Oxide.Plugins
{
    [Info("Sulfur", "Christopher Allen", 0.1)]
    public class Sulfur : RustPlugin
    {
        void OnServerInitialized()
        {
            Puts("Sulfur has been initialized.");
        }

        void OnPlayerInit(BasePlayer player)
        {
            var message = string.Format("{0} has joined the server", player.displayName);
            rust.BroadcastChat({ message });
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can possibly shed some light on why this may be happening, it would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: does `BroadcastChat` takes anonymous type

Comment: Im a bit new to this to say for sure, but in lue of my issue i tried directly passing broadcastchat the player.displayName. it didnt seem to like that.

Comment: Change it to `rust.BroadcastChat(message);`. Also, please tell us the line it's occurring on (saying line 19 is not useful to us because you've omitted the using statement, and your code only has 18 lines).

Comment: Wow! Rob! that worked, thank you. 

Why do you suppose that the API docs suggest to use curly brackets?

Comment: or rust.BroadcastChat(new { message });

Comment: @ChristopherAllen I have no idea, it seems like a mistake in their documentation. There's no way it will work in `C#`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rust.BroadcastChat(message);
```

Get rid of curly brackets that will work, if you have any other questions ask me on steam here: http://steamcommunity.com/id/Bycrome/